# Python objects - avoiding creation of attribute with unknown name

Tags: python, object, attributes

Wishing to avoid a situation like this:

```
>>> class Point:
x = 0
y = 0
>>> a = Point()
>>> a.X = 4 #whoops, typo creates new attribute capital x
```

I created the following object to be used as a superclass:

```
class StrictObject(object):
    def __setattr__(self, item, value):
        if item in dir(self):
            object.__setattr__(self, item, value)
        else:
            raise AttributeError("Attribute " + item + " does not exist.")
```

While this seems to work, the python [documentation says of `dir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir):

> **Note:** Because [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class.

Is there a better way to check if an object has an attribute?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Much better ways.

The most common way is "we're all consenting adults". That means, you don't do any checking, and you leave it up to the user. Any checking you do makes the code less flexible in it's use.

But if you really want to do this, there is [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots) by default in Python 3.x, and for new-style classes in Python 2.x:

> By default, instances of both old and new-style classes have a dictionary for attribute storage. This wastes space for objects having very few instance variables. The space consumption can become acute when creating large numbers of instances.
>
> The default can be overridden by defining `__slots__` in a new-style class definition. The `__slots__` declaration takes a sequence of instance variables and reserves just enough space in each instance to hold a value for each variable. Space is saved because `__dict__` is not created for each instance.
>
> Without a `__dict__` variable, instances cannot be assigned new variables not listed in the `__slots__` definition. Attempts to assign to an unlisted variable name raises `AttributeError`. If dynamic assignment of new variables is desired, then add `'__dict__'` to the sequence of strings in the `__slots__` declaration.

For example:

```
class Point(object):
    __slots__ = ("x", "y")

point = Point()
point.x = 5 # OK
point.y = 1 # OK
point.X = 4 # AttributeError is raised
```

And finally, the proper way to check if an object has a certain attribute is not to use `dir`, but to use the built-in function [`hasattr(object, name)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr).

Comment: `__slots__` seems to allow some internal optimizations as well.

Comment: Another neat use for `__slots__`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good idea to write code to prevent such errors. These "static" checks  should be the job of your IDE. [Pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) will warn you about assigning attributes outside of `__init__` thus preventing typo errors. It also shows many other problems and potential problems and it can easily be used from PyDev.

Comment: pylint doesn't always check this.  see example here: https://github.com/earonesty/pystrict

Answer (score 2):

In such situation you should look what the python standard library may offer you. Did you consider the namedtuple?

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple("Point", "x, y")

a = Point(1,3)

print a.x, a.y
```

Because Point is now immutable your problem just can't happen, but the draw-back is naturally you can't e.g. just add +1 to a, but have to create a complete new Instance.

```
x,y = a
b = Point(x+1,y)
```